# Getting Extended URL from onPageFinished method

Tags: java, android-studio, url

I tried to get the String from inside onPageFinished method but I couldn't find a way
I just want the extended link which exist inside onPageFinished method the problem is no matter what string i use it comes out null

```
 final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

final String[] finalURL = {""};
String url1 = "https://shorturl.at/bFQW9";
myWebView.loadUrl(url1);

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {


    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

        finalURL[0] = myWebView.getUrl();


    }
});
System.out.println(finalURL[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong WebViewClient instance, you set it twice, and load the page on the first instance of WebViewClient you set.
Also there is a chance that finalURL[0] will not be set by the time your call is made to print it out.
The below code takes into account what I said, and should address your issue.
You should handle all things that rely on finalURL[0] inside of onPageFinished.

```
final WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
final String[] finalURL = {""};
String url1 = "https://shorturl.at/bFQW9";

myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        finalURL[0] = myWebView.getUrl();
        System.out.println(finalURL[0]);
    }
});
myWebView.loadUrl(url1);
```

Comment: I am developing an anti phishing system and one of the problems is short links I used myWebView.getUrl(); inside onPageFinished  because that way I will get the original extended URL(i'v tried that and it work) the problem is that value exist only inside onPageFinished  method, I need to copy the value of extended link outside the method so I can search in Blacklist

Comment: Just execute that code from within onPageFinished() otherwise the only other solution is to create something that will wait for the value to be set which will end up blocking your UI thread, or create a callback handler that will execute once onPageFinished() is called, you don't really need the finalURL variable if you structure it correctly